# How to add a 360 video with Google Cardboard support to my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

Im currently developing a mobile app using Flutter and I cant find a way on how to add a 360 video with Google Cardboard support to my Flutter app.

Comment: did you find out any solution ??